# Vmware tags and Ansible , empty out in Ansible but VMs have tags

Tags: linux, scripting, ansible, automation, ansible-playbook

I am trying to filter out the list of VMs with specific tags. The sample playbook is as follows :

```yaml
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
   become: false
   vars:
      vcenter_hostname: vcenter3423
      vcenter_username: center\user4325
      vcenter_password: L0gM3In4325
   tasks:
     - name: Gather all registered virtual machines
       community.vmware.vmware_vm_info:
         hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
         username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
         password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
         validate_certs: no
       delegate_to: localhost
       register: vminfo

     - debug:
         msg: "{{ item.guest_name }}, {{ item.ip_address }}, {{ item.guest_fullname }}, {{ item.datacenter }}, {{ item.power_state }}, {{ item.tags }} "
       with_items:
         - "{{ vminfo.virtual_machines }} | community.general.json_query(query) }}"       
       vars:
         query: "[?guest_name=='CMCUAT']"
```

However, whatever combination I may try the tags[]  output, the rest of the o/p is populated.
Not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons, make sure you have community installed `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general` also modify `debug` to use `json_query`  and you should add a separate query for filtering your VMs

here is your file, replace `specific_tag` in the query with the tag you are looking for

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: vcenter3423
    vcenter_username: center\user4325
    vcenter_password: L0gM3In4325
  tasks:
    - name: Gather all registered virtual machines
      community.vmware.vmware_vm_info:
        hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
        password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
        validate_certs: no
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: vminfo

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.guest_name }}, {{ item.ip_address }}, {{ item.guest_fullname }}, {{ item.datacenter }}, {{ item.power_state }}, {{ item.tags }} "
      with_items: "{{ vminfo.virtual_machines | community.general.json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?guest_name=='CMCUAT' && tags[?contains(@, 'specific_tag')]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your task includes the [`show_tag` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_vm_info_module.html#parameter-show_tag). I missed it in my first go-around. e.g.

```
     - name: Gather all registered virtual machines
       community.vmware.vmware_vm_info:
         hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
         username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
         password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
         show_tag: true
         validate_certs: no
       delegate_to: localhost
       register: vminfo
```